# Long time processing a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-glue

I have a lambda function which basically converts 'CSV files' into 'JSON files',

the problem is depending on the file the execution can take 5 sec or 400 sec maybe more,

Do you think it's, be an excellent solution to use lambda for this case, configuring the timeout for 10 min or something really high?

Comment: I would use Fargate if I already had a Lambda function written. For new projects I would consider AWS Glue to convert file formats (CSV -> Json).

Comment: What do you mean by ' if i had a lambda fonction already written '

Comment: If I already had a lambda function written, I would just port it to a container and run it under Fargate. For a lot of use cases Fargate is a "Fat Lambda". Your use case is a good example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum runtime for a Lambda function is 5 minutes (300s).  So if you expect your runtimes might exceed this, Lambda is not a suitable technology to use.  An AWS product like [Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/) or [Fargate ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) might be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

After a meeting with an AWS technical advisor, i had this solutions :

1. **AWS batch**
2. **AWS Glue**

the AWS GLUE might be a better solution, it's an ETL and it was introduced by AWS for this kind of problem.

So the solution will be an AWS LAMBDA function which calls the AWS GLUE to transform a file from AWS S3, i'll call the LAMBDA through AWS API GATEWAY.